# ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using **spark-1.5.0-cdh5.6.0**. tried the sample application (scala)
command is:

```
> spark-submit --class com.cloudera.spark.simbox.sparksimbox.WordCount --master local /home/hadoop/work/testspark.jar
```

Got the following error:

```
 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/user/spark/applicationHistory does not exist
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:534)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:747)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:524)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:424)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.start(EventLoggingListener.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:541)
        at com.cloudera.spark.simbox.sparksimbox.WordCount$.main(WordCount.scala:12)
        at com.cloudera.spark.simbox.sparksimbox.WordCount.main(WordCount.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Spark has a feature called "history server" which allows you to browse historical events after the `SparkContext` dies. This property is set via setting `spark.eventLog.enabled` to `true`.

You have two options, either specify a valid directory to store the event log via the `spark.eventLog.dir` config value, or simply set `spark.eventLog.enabled` to  `false` if you don't need it.

You can read more on that in the [Spark Configuration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) page.

Comment: @G.Saleh Glad it helped.

Comment: I clicked without noticing

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error which working with nltk in spark, To fix this I just removed all the nltk related properties from spark-conf.default.